# No such module 'heresdk' when building using VSCode

Tags: swift, flutter, here-api

```
...here_sdk/ios/Classes/MapController.swift:14:8: error: no such module 'heresdk'
import heresdk
```

So I'm getting this build error when I try to run the app from VS Code. If I run the app from XCode it runs fine.

Flutter version is 2.5.2 stable. XCode version is 13. iOS version being built for is 15.0. Being built for a simulator.

[Cannot get Flutter app to build - no such module 'heresdk'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69442904/cannot-get-flutter-app-to-build-no-such-module-heresdk)

I've checked out this solution. It doesn't apply to me and neither does it work for me.

Comment: The minimum supported Flutter version was raised from 2.0.6 to 2.2.3. Flutter 2.5.2 (and therefore Dart 2.14.3) is now officially supported. Also arm64 support was added. Try using HERE SDK 4.9.2.0 or newer.

Answer (score 1):

The latest stable Flutter version that works with the HERE SDK the 2.5.2. Newer versions may also work, but are not guaranteed to work.

You can refer this in the Highlights of Version 4.9.1.0 at https://developer.here.com/documentation/flutter-sdk-navigate/4.9.1.0/release_notes/topics/notes_navigate.html#version-4910